# Timing of Postgres Procedures for JSONB

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb, supabase

I'm new to Postgres procedures, and I've created some with triggers that work, but not if I insert a lot of rows at once. My basic setup is this:
I have multiple tables, each for  specific object, and a corresponding history table with previous versions of those objects. They all have the same columns:

```sql
create table if not exists public.appointment (
    id text primary key,
    versionid int not null,
    updatedat timestamp with time zone default timezone('utc'::text, now()) not null,
    resource jsonb not null
);

create table if not exists public.appointmenthistory (
    id text,
    versionid int not null,
    updatedat timestamp with time zone default timezone('utc'::text, now()) not null,
    resource jsonb not null,
    primary key (id, versionid)
);
```

There is a procedure for new objects and for updating objects. These both work appropriately. My triggers for a new object looks like this:

```sql
create trigger new_appointment
  before insert on public.appointment
  for each row execute procedure public.new_resource(); 
create trigger newsearch_appointment
  after insert on public.appointment
  for each row execute procedure internal.search_appointment();
```

The public.new_resource() procedure looks like this:

```sql
create or replace function new_resource()
  returns trigger as $$
  declare  
  resourceid text;
  begin
    -- check if the resource that is being uploaded has an id
    resourceid := new.resource->>'id';
    -- if the resourceid is null (so we have to assume this is a new resource)
    if resourceid is null then
      -- we generate a new id
      resourceid := gen_random_uuid();
    end if;
    -- assign that id to the resource
    new.id := resourceid;
    -- we set the versionid at 1
    new.versionid = 1;
    -- then we ensure the json of the resource agrees
    new.resource := new.resource::jsonb || 
      json_build_object(
        'id',resourceid::text,
        'meta', json_build_object(
          'versionId','1',
            -- record this moment as the moment of updating
          'lastuUdated',to_json(now())::jsonb
        )::jsonb
      )::jsonb;
    -- return the new resource
    return new;
  end;
$$ language plpgsql security definer;
```

But does work as intended. The problem is with the search procedure. Each jsonb object has multiple fields that someone can search on (for instance, you can search for the location, date, and type of appointment - amongst others). My thought was, if you have a million appointments, everytime someone searches, I would have to dig through the jsonb for every appointment in the table. What I've done instead, is create search table that stores the result of all of the searches anytime the object is created or updated. So, for instance, in the search table for appointments, there would be a column for location, another for date, and one for type. Then when a search is performed, I can just look at the values in the columns instead of having to search through all of the json. An abbreviated table looks like this:

```sql
create table if not exists internal.appointmentsearch (
  id text primary key,
  "appointment-type" jsonb,
  "date" jsonb,
  "location" jsonb,
  "patient" jsonb
);
```

And the procedure to insert a new row on this table looks like this:

```sql
create or replace function internal.search_appointment()
  returns trigger as $$
  begin
    insert into internal.appointmentsearch
    (
      id,
      "appointment-type",
      "date",
      "location",
      "patient"
    )
    values
    (
      jsonb_path_query(new.resource, '$.id')::text,
      jsonb_path_query(new.resource, '$.appointmentType'),
      jsonb_path_query(new.resource, '$.start'),
      jsonb_path_query(new.resource, '$.participant.actor[*] ? (@.type like_regex "^.*Location.*") ? (@.reference like_regex "^.*Location.*")'),
      jsonb_path_query(new.resource, '$.participant.actor[*] ? (@.type like_regex "^.*Patient.*") ? (@.reference like_regex "^.*Patient.*")')
    );
  return new;
  end;
$$ language plpgsql security definer;
```

And actually, this all works as I'd like, as long as I'm only inserting one or two objects into the table at a time. However, if I try and insert more than 2, something like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO public.Appointment(resource)
VALUES('{"resourceType":"Appointment","id":"example","meta":{"tag":[{"system":"http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/v3-ActReason","code":"HTEST","display":"test health data"}]},"text":{"status":"generated","div":"<div xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">Brian MRI results discussion</div>"},"status":"booked","serviceCategory":[{"coding":[{"system":"http://example.org/service-category","code":"gp","display":"General Practice"}]}],"serviceType":[{"coding":[{"code":"52","display":"General Discussion"}]}],"specialty":[{"coding":[{"system":"http://snomed.info/sct","code":"394814009","display":"General practice"}]}],"appointmentType":{"coding":[{"system":"http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/v2-0276","code":"FOLLOWUP","display":"A follow up visit from a previous appointment"}]},"reasonReference":[{"reference":"Condition/example","display":"Severe burn of left ear"}],"priority":5,"description":"Discussion on the results of your recent MRI","start":"2013-12-10T09:00:00Z","end":"2013-12-10T11:00:00Z","created":"2013-10-10","comment":"Further expand on the results of the MRI and determine the next actions that may be appropriate.","basedOn":[{"reference":"ServiceRequest/myringotomy"}],"participant":[{"actor":{"reference":"Patient/example","display":"Peter James Chalmers"},"required":"required","status":"accepted"},{"type":[{"coding":[{"system":"http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/v3-ParticipationType","code":"ATND"}]}],"actor":{"reference":"Practitioner/example","display":"Dr Adam Careful"},"required":"required","status":"accepted"},{"actor":{"reference":"Location/1","display":"South Wing, second floor"},"required":"required","status":"accepted"}]}')
ON CONFLICT(id) DO UPDATE SET resource=EXCLUDED.resource
WHERE public.Appointment.id=EXCLUDED.id;
INSERT INTO public.Appointment(resource)
VALUES('{"resourceType":"Appointment","id":"2docs","meta":{"tag":[{"system":"http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/v3-ActReason","code":"HTEST","display":"test health data"}]},"text":{"status":"generated","div":"<div xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">Brian MRI results discussion</div>"},"status":"booked","serviceCategory":[{"coding":[{"system":"http://example.org/service-category","code":"gp","display":"General Practice"}]}],"serviceType":[{"coding":[{"code":"52","display":"General Discussion"}]}],"specialty":[{"coding":[{"system":"http://snomed.info/sct","code":"394814009","display":"General practice"}]}],"appointmentType":{"coding":[{"system":"http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/v2-0276","code":"WALKIN","display":"A previously unscheduled walk-in visit"}]},"priority":5,"description":"Discussion about Peter Chalmers MRI results","supportingInformation":[{"reference":"DiagnosticReport/ultrasound"}],"start":"2013-12-09T09:00:00Z","end":"2013-12-09T11:00:00Z","comment":"Clarify the results of the MRI to ensure context of test was correct","participant":[{"actor":{"reference":"Patient/example","display":"Peter James Chalmers"},"required":"information-only","status":"accepted"},{"actor":{"reference":"Practitioner/example","display":"Dr Adam Careful"},"required":"required","status":"accepted"},{"actor":{"reference":"Practitioner/f202","display":"Luigi Maas"},"required":"required","status":"accepted"},{"actor":{"display":"Phone Call"},"required":"information-only","status":"accepted"}]}')
ON CONFLICT(id) DO UPDATE SET resource=EXCLUDED.resource
WHERE public.Appointment.id=EXCLUDED.id;
INSERT INTO public.Appointment(resource)
VALUES('{"resourceType":"Appointment","id":"examplereq","meta":{"tag":[{"system":"http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/v3-ActReason","code":"HTEST","display":"test health data"}]},"text":{"status":"generated","div":"<div xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">Brian MRI results discussion</div>"},"identifier":[{"system":"http://example.org/sampleappointment-identifier","value":"123"}],"status":"proposed","serviceCategory":[{"coding":[{"system":"http://example.org/service-category","code":"gp","display":"General Practice"}]}],"specialty":[{"coding":[{"system":"http://snomed.info/sct","code":"394814009","display":"General practice"}]}],"appointmentType":{"coding":[{"system":"http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/v2-0276","code":"WALKIN","display":"A previously unscheduled walk-in visit"}]},"reasonCode":[{"coding":[{"system":"http://snomed.info/sct","code":"413095006"}],"text":"Clinical Review"}],"priority":5,"description":"Discussion on the results of your recent MRI","minutesDuration":15,"slot":[{"reference":"Slot/example"}],"created":"2015-12-02","comment":"Further expand on the results of the MRI and determine the next actions that may be appropriate.","participant":[{"actor":{"reference":"Patient/example","display":"Peter James Chalmers"},"required":"required","status":"needs-action"},{"type":[{"coding":[{"system":"http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/v3-ParticipationType","code":"ATND"}]}],"required":"required","status":"needs-action"},{"actor":{"reference":"Location/1","display":"South Wing, second floor"},"required":"required","status":"accepted"}],"requestedPeriod":[{"start":"2016-06-02","end":"2016-06-09"}]}')
ON CONFLICT(id) DO UPDATE SET resource=EXCLUDED.resource
WHERE public.Appointment.id=EXCLUDED.id;
```

I get the following error message:

```sql
Failed to run sql query: null value in column "id" of relation "appointmentsearch" violates not-null constraint
```

My only thought was that there was some kind of timing issue with getting the id from the jsonb before inserting into the table, and if you did it a bunch of times, there was some kind of a scheduler or something that didn't work correctly. But I don't really know. Anyone have any suggestions about why it's doing this and how I can fix it?

Comment: "*everytime someone searches, I would have to dig through the jsonb for every appointment in the table*" - that's what an index should be used for. Your `internal.appointmentsearch` is essentially a materialised view that's implemented with a trigger.

Comment: Are you sure you're getting an error about "*null value in column "id" of relation "appointmentsearch"*"? Because from what I can see, you should get an error about a NULL value in the `id` column of `public.Appointment` itself - you're only inserting something into the `resource` column, and neither `id` nor `versionid` are populated by anything. This seems to be caused by the ids in the data being part of the `resource` json - you should not store it in there if you have a separate column for it.

Comment: So @Bergi would you suggest I just make the entries into the search table indexes instead?

Comment: And that's definitely the error I'm getting. And sorry, I should have posted the procedure new_resource(). It triggers before the insert, and ensures that the object has an id and a versionId.

Comment: Yes, I'd recommend you only define an appropriate index on `public.appointment` and do not create the `internal.appointmentsearch` table at all - but it depends on what queries exactly you're running against it

Comment: Regarding `new_resource()`, you can [edit] your question to include it

Comment: So the problem would be that `jsonb_path_query(new.resource, '$.id')::text` returns NULL? For which of the inserts does that happen? Is it when the `ON CONFLICT UPDATE` triggers? And as suggested, rather use `new.id` instead of extracting the id from the `new.resource`.

Comment: So I updated the primary question to include that new_resource function. And yes, that is exactly the problem. If I run that last bit code, with the inserts, but only insert one object, it works fine. When I insert 2 objects it works fine. But when I try and insert 3 objects, that's when it gives me the error message about null.

Comment: And for the searches, it might be something like, search for an 'appointment-type' of 'outpatient', that's greater than '2020-01-01' and less than '2020-12-31', so for that kind of query, I'd need to know the appointment type for every frow, and then the start value and compare it to the dates above. Each of these would be found using the json_path-query functions above.